# Ingress rewrite to two different services from one DNS

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, url-rewriting, nginx-ingress

I am trying to reach out to two services from my DNS.

Example:- myportal.com

- myportal.com/app1

I have my SSO and SSL implementation on "myportal.com" and on the home page I have a button which calls a service "myportal.com/app1". I have tried multiple things but I am not able to configure both properly.

From below ingress config I am able to redirect to "myportal.com/app1" but its not working properly for "myportal.com". I have tried multiple thing including default backend and its not working for me. When I use default backend then "myportal.com" works but it stops redirecting to /app1.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myportal-ingress-test
  namespace: appspace
  annotations:
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myportal.com
    secretName: secret
  rules:
  - host: myportal.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /
        backend:
          service:
            name: portal-service
            port:
              number: 8097
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /app1(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          service:
            name: app-ui-service
            port:
              number: 8087
```

I am fairly new to kubernetes and I am not sure if it's the correct way to implement such things. I am open to new implementation too if it's using ingress and routing to different services using same dns on different path.

Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this issue. The redirect in an ingress file would work for all the paths, so I created a separate ingress for each path with individual redirects.

Ingress 1 - myportal.com (with SSO and SSL)

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gcpportal-service-test
  namespace: appspace
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/x-forwarded-prefix: /myportal-service
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: 'true'
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myportal.com
    secretName: secret
  defaultBackend:
    service:
      name: myportal-service
      port:
        number: 80
  rules:
  - host: myportal.com
```

Ingress 2 - myportal.com/app1 (application deployed)

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: gcpportal-service-test-1
  namespace: appspace
  annotations:
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myportal.com
    secretName: secret
  rules:
  - host: myportal.com
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /app1(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          service:
            name: app1-ui-service
            port:
              number: 8087
```

This helped me to resolve this issue. I also verified that this way is also a standard way and is provided in one of the documentation of nginx.

https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx/user-guide/ingress-path-matching/

Answer (score 0):

Try below to see if you can save an ingress:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: myportal-ingress-test
  namespace: appspace
  annotations:
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
   nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - myportal.com
    secretName: secret
  rules:
  - host: myportal.com
    http:
      paths:
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /()(.*)      # let rewrite-target get the match $2
        backend:
          service:
            name: portal-service
            port:
              number: 8097
      - pathType: Prefix
        path: /app1(/|$)(.*)
        backend:
          service:
            name: app-ui-service
            port:
              number: 8087
```